# Extract type of field from typescript union

Tags: typescript

I have some complex type, that composed from union of object literals

```
type ComplexType = {
    a: {
        b: number | {
            c: boolean; // want  this type
        };
    } | { e: boolean };
} | string;
```

I wand to get type of field c (boolean). I can actually do it this way

```
type CType1 = Extract<
    Extract<
        Extract<ComplexType, { a?: any }>['a'],
        { b?: any }
    >['b'],
    { c?: any }>['c'];
```

or that

```
type CType2 = Extract<
    Extract<
        Extract<ComplexType, { 'a'?: any }>['a'],
        { 'b'?: any }
    >['b'],
    { 'c'?: any }>['c'];
```

but I think it's kind of ugly

I want to write helper type `PropertyType` and be able to extract type of field as such

```
type CType3 = PropertyType<PropertyType<PropertyType<ComplexType, 'a'>, 'b'>, 'c'>;
```

to this end I tried

```
type PropertyType<T, prop> = Extract<Partial<T>, { prop?: any }>[prop];
```

but this doesn't work -  prop in `{ prop?: any }` is string "prop", not name of the field I want.  I.e. if I write `PropertyType<ComplexType, 'a'>` I want `Extract<Partial<T>, { a?: any }>[a];`
but get `Extract<Partial<T>, { prop?: any }>[a];`
Is it possible to do write type for extracting type of field by field name from union?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `prop` in `{ prop?: any }` does not refer to the type parameter, it is just a property named prop. You need to use `Record` to get a type with a property specified by the `prop` parameter. Also the `Partial` is not necessary on `T`

```
type PropertyType<T, TProp extends PropertyKey> = 
    Extract<T, Partial<Record<TProp, any>>>[TProp];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAGwgDwCrmgXigbwFgAoKMqAQwH4AuAk8xqAIzoDsBXBZiAJygA+9Uk1EBjOszhxUFNgG4oAeiVQA7nOBlgACwCWAZyihIDUVAC+8s2QuCCUCJOmy2l68TtCDwXnrYA5h4kJCbQMFiQAMxQeAAKvHCQvKCREAA8CUl8qdiZicm5kOnwSKiY2AA0UADkFDUAfNU1zI3NYo3BxKHYUFmFIGnpGNUY-Y5owBBsACZG-TkgANIQIA2xUACik7wUYsDD1XEUKXoUyOkAShBicLwzw-3VcmsNDQDaYwUAuvJAA)

Perhaps a simpler version would be to directly use a conditional type:

```
type PropertyType<T, TProp extends PropertyKey> = 
    T extends Partial<Record<TProp, infer TValue>> ? TValue : never
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAGwgDwCrmgXigbwFgAoKMqAQwH4AuAk8xqAIzoDsBXBZiAJygA+9Uk1EBjOszhxUFNgG4oAeiVQA7nOBlgACwCWAZyihIDUVAC+8s2QuCCUCJOmy2l68TtCDwXnrYA5h4kJCbQMFiQAMxQeAAKvHCQvKCREAA8CUl8qdiZicm5kOnwSKiY2AA0UADkFDUAfNU1zI3NYo3BxKHYUFmFIGnpGNUY-Y5owBBsACZG-TkgANIQIA2xUBgTU7PzFCl6FMjpAEoQYnC8M8P91f4AZnybAGpHHBAN61Qvb9DsEAA3PgkeRAA)